# Using hiera to set class parameters?

Tags: puppet, hiera

I am trying to figure out how to use hiera for setting the values for class parameters.
I am testing things out with two simple classes: testhiera and testhiera2

Here are those classes:

```
[root@puppet-el7-001 modules]# cat testhiera/manifests/init.pp 
class testhiera (
        $haproxy_cert_content = 'unknown' ,
) {

        notify {"cert is $haproxy_cert_content":}
}
[root@-puppet-el7-001 modules]# cat testhiera2/manifests/init.pp 
class testhiera2 (
        $haproxy_cert_content = 'unknown' ,
) {

        notify {"number two cert is $haproxy_cert_content":}
}
```

here is my /etc/puppletlabs/puppet/hiera.yaml file

```
---
:backends:
  - yaml
:hierarchy:
  - defaults
  - "%{clientcert}"
  - "%{environment}"
  - global

:yaml:
# datadir is empty here, so hiera uses its defaults:
# - /var/lib/hiera on *nix
# - %CommonAppData%\PuppetLabs\hiera\var on Windows
# When specifying a datadir, make sure the directory exists.
  :datadir: /root/puppetmaster/hiera/ost-el7
```

and I have this file /root/puppetmaster/hiera/ost-el7/defaults.yaml

*a side question: Do I have to name the file "defaults.yaml"? How could I use another file name?*

```
---
testhiera::haproxy_cert_content: "\n
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n
blah blah blha\n
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n
blah blah blha\n
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n
blah blah blha\n
-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n
"
```

When I execute my puppet classes like so ...

```
# puppet apply -e 'include testhiera'
```

... I get the expected output:

```
Notice: Compiled catalog for puppet-el7-001.cisco.com in environment production in 0.08 seconds
Notice: cert is 
 -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
 blah blah blha
 -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
 blah blah blha
 -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
 blah blah blha
 -----END CERTIFICATE-----

Notice: /Stage[main]/Testhiera/Notify[cert is 
 -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
 blah blah blha
 -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
 blah blah blha
 -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
 blah blah blha
 -----END CERTIFICATE-----
 ]/message: defined 'message' as 'cert is 
 -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
 blah blah blha
 -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
 blah blah blha
 -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
 blah blah blha
 -----END CERTIFICATE-----
 '
Notice: Finished catalog run in 0.17 seconds
```

My question is what is the best way to get thehaproxy_cert_content data to the
testhiera2 class? Do I have to change my defaults.yaml file to look like this ...

```
---
testhiera::haproxy_cert_content: "\n
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n
blah blah blha\n
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n
blah blah blha\n
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n
blah blah blha\n
-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n
"
testhiera2::haproxy_cert_content: "\n
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n
blah blah blha\n
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n
blah blah blha\n
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n
blah blah blha\n
-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n
"
```

... basically just cut--n-pasting the lines and changing the testhiera to testhiera2?

I hope someone can show me a better way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Hiera you can reuse already defined variables by using [hiera lookup funcion](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/1/variables.html#the-hiera-lookup-function). In your example it will be:

```
testhiera2::haproxy_cert_content:"%{hiera('testhiera::haproxy_cert_content')}"
```

For side question: Hiera will look up for variables in files in the same order as provided in `hiera.yaml`. (reading about hiera [hierarchy](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/1/configuring.html#hierarchy)) So in your configuration, first it will check file `defaults.yaml`. If it will not find defined variable there it will try to evaluate variable `clientcert` and look in file `value_of_clientcert.yaml`, next in file `value_of_environment.yaml` and at the end in `global.yaml`.

You don't have to name the file `defaults.yaml`. Everything that will match hiera configuration, according to description above, will be good.

*BTW, if you are using facter facts in hiera hierarchy put `::` before the name of variable, so `%{::facter_fact}`.

Comment: Take special note that with that hierarchy, `defaults` will overrule **any** setting elsewhere, which is counter-intuitive. You may wish to rename this layer to `absolutes` or `immutables`, or like as not drop it altogether. `%{clientcert}` is usually a safe choice for top hierarchy level.

Comment: Good observation. Keeping `defaults` as a top of hiera hierarchy is counter-intuitive.  My hiera hierarchy looks like: `  - "%{::my_environment}/%{::hostname}" -%{::my_environment}/defaults"  - defaults `