# hiera use hash as variable

Tags: puppet, hiera

in puppet hiera I have a working construction

```
location_cfg_append: {allow: "127.0.0.1"
    deny: "all"}
```

Can I  replace  it by folowing construction?

```
cf_ips:
    allow: "127.0.0.1"
    deny: "all"

location_cfg_append: %{hiera('cf_ips')}
```

Comment: Why do you want  to do that?

Comment: I think your question is a duplicate. Description how to use hiera lookups in yaml file you can find here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28555303/using-hiera-to-set-class-parameters.

Answer (score 1):

When using [the hiera lookup function](https://puppet.com/docs/hiera/3.3/variables.html#the-hiera-lookup-function) you must use it as a string interpolation function as such the result will be cast to a string, which will likely cause an error.  however you can use [the alias function](https://puppet.com/docs/hiera/3.3/variables.html#the-alias-lookup-function) which preserves the variable type e.g.

```
cf_ips:
  allow: "127.0.0.1"
  deny: "all"

location_cfg_append: "%{alias('cf_ips')}"
```